# Is it recommended to hang on to a synced realm instance? Or re-get it every time?

Tags: swift, realm, mongodb-atlas

I’ve been using non-synced realms for a few apps, and I generally call

```
let realm = try Realm()
// do something...
```

every time I want to do something with data in the realm (instead of instantiating the realm and hanging on to it). I think this is the recommended way of doing things.

However, when working with synced realms, should I be reinstantiating the realm just like when using non-synced realms? For example, should I call:

```
let user = app.user!
let syncedConfiguration = user.configuration(partitionValue: partitionName)
let realm = try await Realm(configuration: syncedConfiguration)
// do something...
```

every time as well? It feels like the call to Realm(configuration: syncedConfiguration) is expensive, but i’m just guessing here.

If I should change the behavior for synced realms, where should I store the realm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So Creating a realm instance isn't super expensive, but opening or closing a transaction can be (this is done in the background by realm itself).

There shouldn't be any problem making a lazy var of realm in your ViewController and using that throughout your code in that VC, just don't make a static reference to a realm instance, as this causes some major issues.

So something like:

```swift
lazy var realm: Realm = {
    let syncedConfiguration = user.configuration(partitionValue: partitionName)
    return try! Realm(configuration: syncedConfiguration)
}()
```

I force unwrap here since the only reason Realm will fail to init is if something is wrong with the way it has been setup, therefore it's a programmer error and can never really be caused at run time.